# How do I compile assets in Yii 2.0.10 on Heroku? Error: The file or directory to be published does not exist: /tmp/build_6de7/vendor/bower/jquery/dist

Tags: heroku, yii2, composer-php

When I try to deploy to Heroku, I'm getting this error.

```
remote: -----> Running 'composer compile'...
remote:        > php yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php
remote:        Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class yii\gii\Module does not exist'
remote:
remote:        in /tmp/build_43b5f0b03599190faf308cbb5640d75d/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:422
remote:
```

I only have `gii` in dev:

`composer.json`

```
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
[...]
"scripts": {
    "compile": [
      "php yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php"
```

`console.php`

```
'bootstrap' => YII_ENV == 'dev' ? ['log', 'gii'] : ['log'],
'modules' => YII_ENV == 'dev' ? [
  'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module'
] : [],
```

It works locally when I set environment to PROD:

```
$ YII_ENV=prod php yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php
[...]
Creating new bundle configuration...
Output bundle configuration created at 'config/assets-prod.php'.
```

By the way it worked in a previous version of Yii2.

This is Yii version 2.0.10.

---

Oops, I needed to run

```
>heroku config:set YII_ENV=prod
```

But now it presents a different error:

```
remote:          - Installing bower-asset/jquery (2.2.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
[...]
remote: -----> Running 'composer compile'...
remote:        > php yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php
remote:        Loading configuration from 'assets.php'...
remote:        Collecting source bundles information...
remote:        Error: The file or directory to be published does not exist: /tmp/build_6de7440629ea20265c495d46245a287a/vendor/bower/jquery/dist
remote:        Script php yii asset assets.php config/assets-prod.php handling the compile event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work. I had to add `composer-asset-plugin` to `composer.json`.

```
"require": {
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.2.0"
```

Not a very helpful error message, especially considering it still installed JQuery from Bower!